# Tomcat 7 Manager script Stop / Start Application

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

I'm using Tomcat 7 and Manager coming from 7.0.32.

```
curl -X PUT http://user:password@server:port/manager/text/deploy?path=/app
OK - it works

curl -X PUT http://user:password@server:port/manager/text/list
FAIL - Unknown command /list
Same with stop : 
FAIL - Unknown command /stop
```

but in the official doc : 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Stop_an_Existing_Application
It's clearly stated that this command exists.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you able to do this using the tomcat manager UI

Comment: Yes no problem with the UI version, I found a way to do it : http://paulgrenyer.blogspot.in/2011/11/catalina-ant-for-tomcat-7.html but needs a bit overhead...

Comment: just answered :'-) PUT is in fact used for deploy only that's why it was working on deploy

Comment: yea completely, but the doc is far to be clear x)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK ... very simple answer : it's not a PUT it's a GET.

```
curl -X GET http://user:password@server:port/manager/text/list
```

I used wireshark to listen on my machine when using tomcat+ant. ( http://paulgrenyer.blogspot.in/2011/11/catalina-ant-for-tomcat-7.html )